# How to connect Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 to Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, remmina

I am using Ubuntu Bionic 18.04, and I want to access my Windows Server 2012 via Remmina or some other tools. I know my ip address, username, and password. Can anyone how can I achieve this with the information above? Thanks.

Comment: This is a server side problem and since you have windows there not our cup of tea (ie. this is off topic). The client only needs a remote desktop app (like remmina). The server needs to have software installed that allows connections to it and that software also informs you about the settings you need for the client to be able to connect.

Comment: so you are saying that it is not possible?